# prepareforSegue Not Passing Data

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

I'm having trouble passing a string (**StringVar**) between view controllers using prepareforSegue.  I've studied various tutorials on this subject, but I'm still unsuccessful (I'm a novice, so the problem might be something obvious).  My code is structured as follows:

**Originating ViewController:**

```
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

//Prepare For Segue:
func prepareforSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
var SVC = segue.destinationViewController as! StudyViewController
SVC.StringVar = "Hello"
}
```

**Destination ViewController:**

```
class StudyViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

var StringVar = String()

//intervening code [omitted]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("StringVar = ", StringVar) 
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

The print statement in the viewDidLoad function works fine, but StringVar remains empty.  Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: Is your `prepareForSegue` executing? I suspect not, because as you've got it, there is a typo. You would find this by using `override`.

Comment: Michael, I initially included a print statement under the prepareforsegue function to verify it was executing.  Nothing printed in the debugger window, but i just assumed that the debugger was cleared instantly by the segue (i guess that was a bad assumption).  What typo do you see?  I tried using override func, but it caused the error "Method does not override any method from its superclass".

Comment: Thanks, I had the "f" in ForSegue as lower case.  Capitalizing it seemed to fix everything.

Comment: Swift 3 Users: prepareforsegue(...) is now prepare(...). This wasted 3 hours of my life and Xcode just ignored the issue.

Answer (score 1):

What @michael was saying is that your prepareForSegue needs to use the override keyword like this:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
       //... code
}
```

Xcode should've corrected to this for you, so make sure you check your spelling. If you don't include the `override` keyword then you are simply defining a new function named `prepareforSegue`.

You can download a working example of prepareForSegue in action from my tutorial here:

[prepareForSegue project files](https://www.codebeaulieu.com/29/prepareForSegue)

Comment: Dan once I capitalized the f in "ForSegue" the compiler began prompting me to include the override keyword.   Thanks for the info. and link

Comment: No problem. As a rule of thumb, let Xcode stub the code out for you. You'll get the latest syntax with no typos!